# Fetch my own updates from linkedin and display on my website - anonymous users

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a company profile in linkedin. I have some updates in the profile. Now i need to fetch the records from linked and display on my website. It should be visible to the anonymous user also.

Did anyone implement such kind of code. Using only javascript or REST service. Please suggest some links. I have searched but no use.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, the [LinkedIn API terms of service](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-apis-terms-use) do not allow you to show data to un-authenticated users. Your options are to:

1. Authenticate the user and pull your profile data using their credentials, or
2. Use a pre-built plugin like the [Member Profile plugin](https://developer.linkedin.com/plugins/member-profile-plugin-generator) to display data to unauthenticated users.